# How to get backend header in a nginx proxy configuration?

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have a Nginx server configured as a proxy, and would like to use the value of a custom header sent by the backend to do something in nginx.

Below is what I have tried but without success:

```
http {
    upstream backend {
        server 123.456.789.10:80;
        keepalive 50;
    }

    map $upstream_http_x_cacheable $iscacheable {
        default "0";
        ~*yes "1";
    }

    server {
        location / {
            proxy_pass  http://123.456.789.10:80;
            if ($iscacheable = "1") {
                #do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to get the result from the backend `X-Cacheable` header (in this case apache) and if it has the word `yes`, it will do something.

Comment: This is a very very important question for me, I pay if necessary to have an answer.

Comment: You may get a response's header in header_filter phase, but what do you want to do at this point? You may change the response's headers and even body, log something. Using OpenResty/Lua you may do something at this phase, even calling external API using some tricks. But you cannot change the nginx behavior on early phases (rewrite, access, content).